# What do I need to put in pfile to change NLS_CHARACTERSET?

Tags: oracle-12c, docker

Im not an expert in databases. I am using docker Oracle 12c database for local dev environment. Its an official image from Oracle but they dont give any option to change the NLS_CHARARACTERSET during database creation and it defaults to AL32UTF8. I need to match our test database which is using WE8MSWIN1252. I have tried modifying the charset after db startup but seems to cause lots of issues as WE8MSWIN1252 is not a superset of AL32UTF8. So I was thinking to set it correctly at the start. I found a way to modify the pfile on startup which I think is where it should be set but Im not sure what to put in there.

```
ORCLCDB.__data_transfer_cache_size=0
ORCLCDB.__db_cache_size=0
ORCLCDB.__inmemory_ext_roarea=0
ORCLCDB.__inmemory_ext_rwarea=0
ORCLCDB.__oracle_base='/u01/app/oracle'#ORACLE_BASE set from environment
*.__shared_io_pool_size=0
*.java_pool_size=0
*.large_pool_size=0
*.shared_pool_size=0
*.streams_pool_size=0
*.audit_file_dest='/u02/app/oracle/audit/ORCLCDB'
*.audit_trail='db'
*.compatible='12.2.0'
*.control_files='/u02/app/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/cntrlORCLCDB.dbf','/u03/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/ORCLCDB/cntrlORCLCDB2.dbf'
*.db_block_size=8192
*.db_files=250
*.db_name='ORCLCDB'
*.db_recovery_file_dest='/u03/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area'
*.db_recovery_file_dest_size=17814m
*.diagnostic_dest='/u01/app/oracle'
*.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLCDBXDB)'
*.enable_pluggable_database=true
*.filesystemio_options='setall'
*.nls_language='AMERICAN'
*.nls_territory='AMERICA'
*.open_cursors=300
*.processes=300
*.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
*.db_domain='localdomain'
*.sga_target=5120M
*.pga_aggregate_target=3072M
*.db_domain='localdomain'
*.sga_target=1280M
*.pga_aggregate_target=768M
```

I thought maybe I could just add this at the bottom of the file but its not working and database fails to start:

```
*.nls_characterset='WE8MSWIN1252'
```

results in

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
ORA-32003: error occured processing parameter 'nls_characterset'
LRM-00101: unknown parameter name 'nls_characterset'
```

What do I need to update to get it to use this character set from the initial creation?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at the [create database command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE.html#GUID-ECE717DF-F116-4151-927C-2E51BB9DD39C), specifically the "national character set" .

Answer (score 0):

Its worth to check this doc id as it looks similar to your context.

Changing the NLS_CHARACTERSET to AL32UTF8 / UTF8 (Unicode) in 8i, 9i , 10g and 11g (Doc ID 260192.1)